# I want more, more, more - options: unanswered, my topics, newest

Tags: feature-request

Searching unanswered questions, I can choose

- my tags
- newest
- votes
- no answers

Well - that's fine, I want them all!

Not exactly, I take 1, 2, and 4; 1 and 4 as filter, and sorted by 2.

Coulnd't there be an list of checkboxes for filtering, and a list of radiobuttons for ordering?

- filter: [] my tags [] no answers
- sort by:(.) newest ( ) votes

Where the filtering could be both on, both off, one of them on and sort order be one the both?

The optimal graphical solution is of course up to you, and the hard work of implementation.

But after dividing filter- and sort-functions, more of both options could be used, like a 'sort by views'-option, suggested in the comments.

Comment: While we're at it, how about a "Sort by Views" option?