# answers:0 integrated into the newest tag and advanced search option with buttons

Tags: feature-request

Thank you for your work. In [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/pr.probability?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50) in order to search for the newest unanswered questions one has to add ["answers:0"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122898/an-option-to-display-newest-unanswered-questions?newreg=df9c80aaa9f94f1da8ae0c5495221bb8) in the search bar.

My suggestion is to give us the option in which chronological order to have the unanswered questions presented. For example, on the bar when clicking the "unanswered" tab 
presenting us with the further options of "newest to oldest" and "oldest to newest". Because especially in math, most old questions that remain unanswered, are in fact open problems that have been looked at hundreds of times. So it is more beneficial to have the quick option to see questions from a [certain period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/allow-searching-for-questions-that-are-still-unanswered-after-some-period-of-tim) or the newest ones.

In general I agree in adding more options as [buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100335/i-want-more-more-more-options-unanswered-my-topics-newest) rather than having to add long lines of code in our search bar for the more [intricate options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/allow-searching-for-questions-that-are-still-unanswered-after-some-period-of-tim). For example, similar to google's "Tools", creating an advanced search tab containing many options to choose from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having can be solved with [custom question lists aka filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/323179):

> [image: filter for newest unanswered by tag]